# How do I fix Webpack from mangling my code in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, bitcoin

I'm building an application using BitcoinJS, and have found that using the `-p` flag causes webpack to mangle certain parts, breaking the ability to produce transactions.

I was advised to use `noParse` with `alias` in the config, which made the problem worse (the entire application would not load at all).

So far I have not found any workaround other than turning off production (which leaves all sorts of strange things in the javascript file, including my local development paths).

**Example project available here** (with install instructions, and how to reproduce): https://github.com/Someguy123/example-webpack-issue

**EDIT/UPDATE**: @bebraw has provided a working solution, which is available on the `fixed` branch in the example project if anyone else wanted to see it in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Uglify mangles too much by default in your case. As per [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) instructions, you need to exclude certain names like this:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: {
            except: [
                'Array', 'BigInteger', 'Boolean', 'Buffer',
                'ECPair', 'Function', 'Number', 'Point'
            ]
        }
    })
]
```

Use `webpack` instead of `webpack -p` after configuring the plugin.

It will make the resulting bundle a little larger, but it will work.

Another alternative would be to generate the bundle separately for **bitcoinjs-lib** elsewhere and then consume that instead. You would have to take mangling into account there as well, but it would keep your project a little neater.